# Как вручную удалить Miner Ethash?

Tags: безопасность

увидел сегодня такую прелесть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сожрала 30 гб

вродь говорят что эт майнер. я видел подозрительную активность компа, но на вирусы не грешил (стоит нод). но видать хрень он.

как найти и удалить вредоноса? в автозагрузке ничего нет. советую прибить ctfhost.exe но и такого у меня нет. только вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что делать?

Comment: Спросите тех кто говорит что это майнер. Удалите каталог если вы считаете что он вам не нужен.

Comment: Обнаружил данный майнер(eth). использовался через предположительно BlueStacks2 эмулятор андроида. Даже при скачивании с официального сайта. Игра castle ClashЖ эра питомцев.
могу предположить создает c:\Users\IRKA\AppData\Local\Ethash\
файлы размером 1.8гб.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не по теме сайта.

Answer (score 3):

Закройте все программы, временно выгрузите антивирус, файрволл и прочее защитное ПО.
**Важно!** на Windows Vista/7/8 AVZ запускайте через контекстное меню проводника от имени Администратора. [Выполните скрипт в АВЗ](http://virusinfo.info/showthread.php?t=7239) (Файл - Выполнить скрипт):

```
begin
 TerminateProcessByName('C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Corel\Java\jusched.exe');
 QuarantineFile('C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Corel\Java\jusched.exe','');
 DeleteFile('C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Corel\Java\jusched.exe','32');
 DeleteFile('C:\Windows\system32\Tasks\Java Update Schedule','64');
ExecuteSysClean;
RebootWindows(true);
end.
```

**Внимание!** Будет выполнена перезагрузка компьютера.

[Источник](http://virusinfo.info/showthread.php?t=192828#post_1332690)

Comment: @Abyx, исправил, спасибо за совет